# Error in crowdsale code on Ethereum

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs

I wanted to do it on private blockchain crowdsale, I did everything according to the instructions on the site https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale#unlimited-crowdsale, but when I copied the last code I got an error when trying to compile it. How can I fix it? [image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Alex, in the `token` contract inside of transfer function you have unused variables and Remix IDE returns warnings, not errors. I'd recommend to compile this contracts in Remix and modify it there for your needs. https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js

Comment: Thank you for answer! Do not tell me how the contract compiled in redmix is ​​attached to the mist? The question can be stupid, but I'm just starting to understand. If you can write in Russian please.